# Display control on another panel

Tags: c#, user-controls, panel

I have on my winform two panels:on the  first panel I have an `usercontrol` that can be multiplied dynamically. I want,on the second panel,to be displayed the `usercontrol` that is selected by the user. The idea is that,I want ,if I change the text at runtime of my `usercontrol` ,these changes to be displayed on the second panel too. I need an idea how can I do that. I am trying now to create properties for each object of my `usercontrol` and events,but I think is too much to do for this. . Thanks.
My code,what I have tried so far:

On my usercontrol I have created properties for each object that this contains. Code on usercontrol.cs:

```
  public string TextName
    {
        get { return textname.Text; }
        set { textname.Text = value; }
    }
    public string Task
    {
        get { return checkboxTip.Text; }
        set { checkboxTip.Text = value; }
    }
       .......
     and on my winform.cs I created an event for all properties:

    private void PropertiesChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       textname1.Text=textname.Text; //textname1 is the textbox from usercontrol,and                     textname is from the second panel;
      checkboxTip1.Text-checkbox.Text;
    .....// I am doing this for each object,but I have 10 objects.
```

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us?

Comment: Yes. I edit now my comment with my code.

Comment: If you can show us some codes I can improve my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. My question was,if I can make a copy/clone of my selected usercontrol,somehow..simpler

Comment: That's exactly I'm trying to do. For every action on your control in 1st panel should have a corresponding action on the 2nd. That's the only method I know.

Comment: Yes. But I thought  that it exists  an easier method to do that. Because I have a lot of objects inside of my usercontrol. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

   textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
   // you can do anytihng here
}
```

assuming that `textBox1` is on your 1st panel and `textBox2` is at your 2nd.